# Mongoose update query - Mongoose/Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection called student, now I want to update the object value inside array based on condition. Can anyone help me to figure this logic please.

**Student:**

```
{
_id: "5996d10e0b992e5def651db4"
name: "Siva"
mark:[
{subject:"Tamil",mark:"50"},
{subject:"English",mark:"25"},
{subject:"Science",mark:"25"},
]
__v: 36
}
```

**Expected Result:**
I want to update only Tamil mark by checking the subject value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update sub-array element or object by using positional operator `$`, in your example it should something like this:

```js
Student.update(
    { "mark.subject": "Tamil" },
    { "$set": { "mark.$.mark": "60" } }
)
```

You can read more documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer... will try this yours.